# Steam game positive/negative recommendations

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Is there a way to retrieve amount of positive/negative recommendations for a steam game?

I've found appdetails function, but it only returns total recommendations number:

"recommendations":{"total":5782}

E.g.
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690

Answer (score 0):

If this data doesn't exist in the JSON response you're getting from the api, not a chance mate :(